# Mesos and spark cluster limited Mesos tasks to two

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, mesos

I want to run a spark application on a mesos cluster. Deploy mode will be cluster mode. From Mesos Web UI I see I have the following:

```
Resources
CPUs    GPUs    Mem     Disk
Total   64  0   60.5 GB     68.0 GB
Allocated   6   0   4.5 GB  0 B
Offered     0   0   0 B     0 B
Idle    58  0   56.0 GB     68.0 GB
```

When running my application with no extra configuration options I get one spark executor with 27 cores allocated thus one Mesos Task. If I run it like this

```
spark-submit --conf spark.executor.cores=4 --conf spark.max.cores=26.....
```

I would expect to see 6 executors of 4 cores each, according to [this link here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-mesos.html#coarse-grained). But What I get is always 2 executors with 4 cores each. Tried many configuration combinations like

```
spark.executor.cores 2 and spark.max.cores 10 to get 5 executors
```

but all I got was 2 executors(Mesos Tasks) with 2 cores each. 
Could you provide with some assistance on how can I achieve the number of executors I want on my Mesos cluster?

Comment: Can you attach logs from Mesos and spark ideally with offers information.

Comment: Do you have a link to your task? I believe you need to set these parameters inside your task.